# Generic app for connecting to wireless hard drive

Tags: android, linux, wireless, ssd

I'm looking for Android and/or Linux based apps/software that will enable connecting to wireless external storage devices e.g. the Seagate Wireless Plus. From what I have read, the hard drives work fine, but the proprietary apps provided by Seagate and other manufacturers are simply not reliable. I'm therefore looking for a generic app/software that will run on my android phone/tablet and ideally also on my Ubuntu laptop. Any suggestions will be much appreciated!